# Find the value of $\frac{w+1}{1-w}$ given that $w^2=-1$

Tags: complex-numbers, contest-math

> #### Question
>
> There is a new real number $w$ such that $w^2 = -1$. If all the laws of arithmetic applies, find the value of $\dfrac{w+1}{1-w}$ .

I tried the following:

$$\frac{w+1}{1-w} = \frac{(w+1)^2}{(1-w)(w+1)} = \frac{2w}{2} = w$$

Then I got stuck... how do I evaluate $w$ (for the test I just put the answer $\sqrt{-1}$. Is this answer correct?

Comment: It is correct. On the other hand, if I had written the question for the test, I would have omitted the word 'real'...

Comment: Are you sure it is a math contest? Hmmm...Then this may be a tricky question...

Comment: @ajotatxe - this is called "Keepin' it real".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite simply $w.$ One can show readily that $-w$ is also a square root of $-1,$ so $\sqrt{-1}$ is ambiguous.